# Relating proof of triangle inequality to properties of order relation

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I'm using the book "Mathematical Analysis" by Brend S.W Schroder.

On page $7$, he tried to relate the proof for $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ to the properties of order relation, specifically, "If $x \leq y$ then $x+z \leq y+z$.
But it leaves me really lost as to how the proof connects with the properties of order relation.

Any explanation is appreciated.

Here is the extract:

Theorem $1.10$ part $2$: If $x \leq y$ then $x + z \leq y + z$.

To prove the triangle inequality $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$, first note that for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $x \leq |x|$. This is clear for $x \geq 0$ and for $x < 0$ we simply note $x <0 < -x = |x|$. Moreover, for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ we have $-x \leq |x|$. Now let $x,y$, be in $\mathbb{R}$. If the inequality $x+y \geq 0$ holds then by part $2$ of Theorem $1.10$ at least one of $x, y$ is greater than or equal to $0$. Hence, by part $2$ of Theorem $1.10$ 
$$|x+y| = x+y \leq |x|+y \leq |x|+|y|.$$

Comment: what is your question? it seems that you posted the explanation already?

Comment: I did posted an explanation by the book but I do not follow his explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt at explaining the details with my own words:

The author first checks that, for any $x$ (positive or negative), one has $x\le \lvert x\rvert$. From this he deduces, by part 2, that
$$x+y\le \lvert x\rvert+y. $$
In turn, $y\le\lvert y\rvert$, hence
$$ \lvert x\rvert+y\le\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert. $$
The conclusion follows by transitivity of the $\le$  relation. This settles the case $x+y\ge 0$.

The case $x+y$ would follow changing $x$ into $-x$, $y$ into $-y$.

Comment: Here's the attempt in case x+y<0:

In case $$x+y<0,$$ it must be true that $$(x<0\wedge y<0)$$
$$\text{x$\in \mathbb{R}$ is negative IFF -x$\in $}\mathbb{R}^+$$
$$\text{x + y $<$ 0 $<$ -(x + y) = (-x)+(-y) = x + y $<$ $|$x$|$ + y $<$ $|$x$|$ + $|$y$|$
   ($\forall $x$\land \forall $y)$\in \mathbb{R}$}$$
Does this looks right?

Comment: No. You may have $x+y<0$ while $x$ and $y$ have different signs (take $x=1, y=-2$, for instance. It is simpler to note, in case $x+y<0$, that $\lvert x+y\rvert=-x-y$ and work with $-x, -y\,$ (don't forget $\lvert -x\rvert =\lvert x\rvert $.